# Backend-as-a-service that requires login for write access?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, single-page-application

I'm trying to write a javascript single-page-app that allows users to login and then, once logged in, create/modify records in a database. I'd like to avoid having my own server side scripts if possible, instead using something like Parse.com, Kinvey.com, or Cloudmine.me.

My issue is that these services have user login capacity but use API keys to determine whether your app has write access. They don't seem to let you have write access once your user is logged in. The only way I can think of to accomplish this is to store a write-access API key in the user's user data, so I'd have the user login, fetch the hidden API key, then change the API key of the app to use that one, so they'll have write access. Obviously this isn't very secure because once that API key is sent over the network, that user will have write-access even if we delete their account or they change their password.

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, so feel free to let me know. Hopefully this made sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to restrict access to a group of users using `Parse.ACL`: http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.ACL.html

If you want to control access on a per user basis then you will have to maintain a custom property on the user object. Then you can check the custom property in the `BeforeSaveRequest()` function and decide whether the user has write access: http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.BeforeSaveRequest.html

Comment: Interesting, so the ACL would apply to all objects (including future ones), so it'd require a login to modify them? In other words, this will require users to be logged in to write anything?

Comment: I think I've figured it out - I disabled the "Allow client class creation" option in settings, and will have a beforeSave on the existing classes to confirm the user is logged in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, most BaaS providers should provide collection level security and some even offer per entry security via ACL's (Access Control Lists).

Kinvey for instance has several variations on collection level security:
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/guides/security#Collectionlevelpermissions

The default security level of `Shared` make it so the user has access to read everything in the collection but can only write to their own items. You may also want to use the `Private` security level to make it so you can only read and write to your own items.

If you want to have more fine-grained control over security you can utilize entry level permissions:
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/guides/security#Entitylevelpermissions

With entry level permissions you can give fine grained access to a specific user or groups of users that you manage. You can even determine what level of security a user has to your entry, read or write. If you have a need to go even finer with control you have full access to write your own security utilizing Business Logic.

Full Disclosure - I am an engineer at Kinvey.